# How do you use Texstudio with github

Tags: texstudio, git, software

How do you use texstudio with github now that texstudio have native git support I don't know what are the options as the answers relate to older versions of texstudio without git support. Thank you.

Comment: As I understand it, you can't use TeXstudio to create a repo. But you can work inside one. Is there something new about git support? This is included for some time now.